# Render flux:field.inline.fal from page in content

Tags: fedext

I have defined a a FAL resource in my page template

```
<flux:field.inline.fal name="imageLinkboxMenu"
                             clear="true"
                             label="FAL image"
                             showThumbs="true"
                             allowedExtensions="jpg,jpeg,gif,png"
                             maxItems="1"/>
```

Now i want display this image in a conent element which refers to this page. I'm not able to get the page resource. I tried a

```
<flux:form.data field="tx_fed_page_flexform" table="pages" uid="{root}" as="fluxPageData">
    {fluxPageData.imageLinkboxMenu}
</flux:form.data>
```

Which only returns `1`. I also tried to acces the field via `v:page.resource.fal` which can not work from my point of view since this does not extract the data from the XML

```
<v:resource.image identifier="{v:page.resources.fal(field: 'imageLinkboxMenu') -> v:iterator.extract(key: 'id') -> v:iterator.first()}" as="resources" />
```

Any hints for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some trial and error I finally got it work. The trick was to add to uid of the page. So I ended up with something like

```
<v:resource.image identifier="{v:page.resources.fal(field: 'imageLinkboxLogo', uid: '{root}') -> v:iterator.extract(key: 'id')}" />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks that work for me too, but the image is not displayed because of encoding. I get this `http%3A//` instead of `http://` could you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't now why but it not work for some translation pages. I receive empty area. Aslo here https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Field/Inline/FalViewHelper.html we see Usage warning. So i recommend alternatively, you could use `<flux:field.file>`.